# Button deletes in array but not in View

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm having trouble removing image in my scrollView, i put my images in UIScrollView then add button, when clicked will prompt an alert view asking if you want to delete it. When yes, deletes in my `NSDocumentDirectory` but not in my View. My images is from `NSDocumentDirectory` picked from an `ImagePicker`.

```
- (void)addImage:(UIImage *)image {
    [_images addObject:image];
    [_thumbs addObject:[image imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(60, 60)]];
    [self createScrollView];
}

- (void) createScrollView {

    [scrollView setNeedsDisplay];
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < _thumbs.count; ++i) {

        UIImage *thumb = [_thumbs objectAtIndex:i];
        UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(column*60+10, row*60+10, 60, 75);
        [button setImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag = i; 

        [scrollView addSubview:button];

        if (column == 4) {
            column = 0;
            row++;
        } else {
            column++;
        }

    }
   [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, (row+1) * 60 + 10)];
}

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
        _clickedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        UIAlertView *saveMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                              message:@"DELETE？"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"NO"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
        [saveMessage show];  
   }

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
if([title isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
            UIButton *button = _clickedButton;
            [button removeFromSuperview];
            [_images objectAtIndex:button.tag];
            [_images removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];

            NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"images%lu.png", button.tag]];
            [fileManager removeItemAtPath: fullPath error:NULL];
            NSLog(@"image removed");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        self.slotBg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(43, 370, 310, 143)];
        CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        gradient.frame = self.slotBg.bounds;
        gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil];
        [self.slotBg.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
        [self.view addSubview:self.slotBg];
        self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,300.0f,130.0f)];
        [slotBg addSubview:self.scrollView];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [_thumbs removeAllObjects];
    for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
    { 
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"oneSlotImages%d.png", i]]; 
        NSLog(@"savedImagePath=%@",savedImagePath);
        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
            [self addImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath]]; 
            NSLog(@"file exists");
        } 
    } 
    NSLog(@"Count : %d", [_images count]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `createScrollView` each time you add an image to your array. What it seems to be doing is creating buttons containing the same image on top of each other. Your code seems to be removing it from the view, but it looks like there are similar buttons just below it. So call `createScrollView` only after you've added all the images and remove it from your `addImage:`.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
{ 
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"oneSlotImages%d.png", i]]; 
    NSLog(@"savedImagePath=%@",savedImagePath);
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
        [self addImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath]]; 
        NSLog(@"file exists");
    } 
}
[self createScrollView];
```

Comment: It won't update the images in the scrollview when I add another image.

Comment: @Kobe.o4 : If you mean when you call if outside of viewDidAppear: , then you must write code to make sure it adds it to the scroll view. Otherwise, a quick fix would be to call [scrollview.subviews valueForKey:@"removeFromSuperview"] in the beginning of createScrollView. Not the best way to go about it obviously, but will get it done.

Comment: what I am doing is remove all the _thumbs, then reload it again.

Comment: @Kobe.o4 But even if you do that, your buttons will still be inside the scrollview. Did you try implementing my answer?

Comment: @Kobe.o4 Could you tell me what exactly is happening when you tried the above code + [scrollview.subviews valueForKey:@"removeFromSuperview"] ?

Answer (score 0):

set tag value to button.then get the button in the following function by

```
    (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
         UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)[scrollview viewWithTag:button.tag];
         //your button tag
         [btn removeFromSuperView];
}
```

---

Comment: then use NSLog to print the button reference in both places where you are creating and removing.

Answer (score 0):

```
//after deleting the image from document directory just call viewDidAppear again...

[self viewDidAppear:yes];
```

Hope this will help you...

Comment: yes before calling it try to run following code.. 
    NSArray *arr = [scrollView subViews];
    for(UIView *view in arr)
           [view removeFromSuperView];
    then call [self viewDidAppear:yes];

Answer (score 0):

try this method :

```
- (void)removeObjectWithTag:(int)objectTag
{
    [_thumbs removeObjectAtIndex:objectTag];

    for (UIView *view in scrollView.subviews)
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeZero;
    [self createScrollView];
}
```